# Am I implementing negative lookaheads correctly with my regex?

Tags: regex

I'm a beginner with regex and stuck with creating regex with the following conditions:

- Minimum of 8 characters
- Maximum of 60 characters
- Must contain 2 letters
- Must contain 1 number
- Must contain 1 special character
- Special character cannot be the following: & ` ( ) =  [ ] | ; " ' < >

So far I have the following...

```
(?=^.{8,60}$)(?=.*\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]{2,})(?!.*[&`()=[|;"''\]'<>]).*
```

But my last two tests are failing and I have no idea why...

1. !@#$%^*+-_~?,.{}!HR12345
2. 123456789AB!

If you'd like to see my test and expected results, visit here: https://regexr.com/73m2o

My tests contains acceptable number of characters, appropriate number of alphabetic characters, and supported special characters... I don't know why it's failing!

Comment: Aside, are you aware you can tune each test case in regexr to expect a match/not match using the dropdown on right hand side? I've changed them for your "expect fail" test cases in [this fork](https://regexr.com/73m3d) as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue is that you're missing the `.*` in `(?=[a-zA-Z]{2,})`. However, your implementation of "two or more" letters is not correct unless the letters must be consecutive.

You'll see that the string `1234567B89A!` fails to match, even with the correction. You can fix this like so:

```
(?=^.{8,60}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[&`()=[|;"''\]'<>]).*
```

The part I changed is `(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])` asserting that we can match a letter, zero or more other characters, and then another letter.

https://regex101.com/r/jEsK0S/1

Also, there's currently no assertion that there must be a special character, only an assertion of which ones shouldn't match. So I'd suggest adding another lookahead with a list of valid special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.*` to verify a character in the string can be very inefficient and I would suggest using [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for the [principle of contast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

Apart from that, there is a point in the question `Must contain 1 special character` that is not addressed yet in the current answers.

You can use a positive lookahead for that to assert one of the characters that you consider special.

```
^(?=[^\d\n]*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^!@#$%^\n]*[!@#$%^])[^&`()=[|;"''\]'<>\n]{8,60}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string (Outside of the lookahead)
- `(?=[^\d\n]*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])` Assert 2 chars a-zA-Z
- `(?=[^!@#$%^\n]*[!@#$%^])` Assert a "special" character
- `` [^&`()=[|;"''\]'<>\n]{8,60} `` Match 8-60 characters except for the ones that you don't want to match
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/68X8U5/1).

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2+ alphabetical characters can appear anywhere in the string, you need to prepend your check for them with `.*` (as you have with the other character classes you're checking for); otherwise the positive lookaheads will, in this scenario, try to assert their appearance at the beginning of the string (position 0):

```
(?=^.{8,60}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2,})(?!.*[&`()=[|;"''\]'<>]).*
```

Comment: Also ensure you add the multiline flag because you're using `^` and `$`. In regexr you can find this in a dropdown box in the top right corner of the window.